# Android with two displays(LCD and HDMI)

Tags: android, texas-instruments

I am working with TI board, currently flashed with Android Marshmallow. I have enabled LCD and HDMI.

current scenario, screen mirror is happening i,e both LCD and HDMI showing same contents.

I want to have video playback on LCD and other application running on HDMI(My own apk running on HDMI).

How to do it?any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Arun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app is the one playing the video, you can use `Presentation` to control what goes on the secondary display, independently of what your app shows on the primary display. In your case, I would guess that the primary display is the LCD and the secondary display is the HDMI monitor, though that is just a guess

If your app is not playing the video, you would have to arrange to control the secondary display via a `Service`, given that you are running on Android 6.0. I have [some code for that](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-presentation#usage-presentationservice), but writing a complex UI this way may be difficult.